# Powershell remote get-process works, start-process doesn't

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I'm new to Powershell, so forgive me if this is a basic question. I've enabled psremoting, but for some reason, while

```
invoke-command -computername MyComputer {get-process}
```

works,

```
invoke-command -computername MyComputer {start-process "c:\windows\system32\calc.exe"}
```

doesn't. I don't get an error message. Rather than the calculator app starting, nothing happens and I get no feedback. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why would you run `"c:\windows\system32.exe"` to start the calculator?

Comment: assuming you running `calc.exe` and not `system32.exe`:
when you use `invoke-command` to start a process on a remote computer, it doesn't start on the interactive session. so you will not see the calculator window on the remote computer. but if you look in task manager (or run `get-process`) you will see the process is actually running.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician No good reason. Just because I'm just using the calculator as a test. Once I figure this out, a path to an exe will go there.

Comment: @Mosheperez Yeah, that was a typo, thanks. I see, it starts the process but no the interactive session. How would I go about starting the interactive session?

Comment: @beezle there is no simple way to do it with PowerShell. you can use psexec instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec